# Java NIO read() End Of Stream

Tags: java, nio, socketchannel

I'm using Java NIO in to accept, read and write in my server.

In the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) it said that the `SocketChannel.read()` function will return the number of bytes read from socket, and -1 if it reach end of stream.

Now - i don't really understand what does `"End Of Stream"` mean? is it as same as `borken pipe` error ?

Does it mean that the connection is lost for both side and i should close the SocketChannel ?

I would be really great full if someone can explain more about it - and give some example of using and behaving correctly according to it..

Comment: End of stream means that there is nothing more to read. I.e. you have read all the data in the stream (end of file).

Comment: doesn't it what int read = read() ---> read = 0 means ? that it read nothing ? and there is nothing to read ?

Comment: It means, all data have been read from stream, but stream can be alive .

Comment: so to sum things up - when the connection got lost during the read() - the indication for it is the Exception and the return from read()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

End Of Stream means there is nothing more to read because the other end has closed the stream.

The value is `0` is not nothing, it is a zero.

You will get an exception if the connection is lost unexpectedly. I.e. the other end had not closed the connection gracefully.